# How to Create a Dynamic Drop Down List in PHP populated from MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dynamic drop down list using PHP and mysql database. I have written the following code and its giving me the output, but the problem is that its showing different drop-down menu for each item, I want all items in a single drop down list. Kindly check it and guide me.

```
        $select_query=          "Select name from category";
        $select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);
        while   ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
        {
            foreach ($select_query_array as $select_query_display)
            {
                echo "  
                    <select>
                        <option value='' >$select_query_display</option>                        
                    </select>
                ";


                }

            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the inner foreach loop... it is doing nothing for you and move the start and end select tags outside of the while loop.

```
$select_query=          "Select name from category";
$select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);
echo "<select name='category'>";
while ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
{
   echo "<option value='' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"])."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response! It is working !! :)

Answer (score 1):

take look at this code.

```
$select_query=          "Select name from category";
$select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);

echo "<select>";
while   ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
{
        echo "<option value='' >".$select_query_array['name']."</option>";                        
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT coloumn_name FROM table_name;" );
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))    
{
    echo "<option value='" . $row['selected_coloumn']. "'>" . $row['selected_coloumn'] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

In this example please select your `'coloumn_name'` and `'table_name'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select_query= "Select name from category";
$select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);
$selectTag = "<select>";
while   ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) ){
    foreach ($select_query_array as $select_query_display){
        $selectTag .="<option value='' >$select_query_display</option>";
    }
}
$selectTag .= "</select>";

   echo $selectTag;
```

Comment: It is working, but its showing duplicate records. I didn't give it negative points. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try it

```
    $select_query=          "Select name from category";
    $select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);
    $select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run)
    $select = "<select>";
    foreach ($select_query_array as $val)
    {
        $select .= "<option value='".$val['name']."' >".$val['name']."</option>"; 


    }

    $select = "</select>";

    echo $select;
```

Hope It will work