# When I choose 'any' option from select type and click submit, I want to display all the data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display all the data from table in MySQL database when I choose 'any' option. I don't know how to do that. Please look at the code below.

```
<form method="post" action="listing_grid.php">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="formBlock select">
                    <label for="location">Property for: </label><br/>
                     <select name="property_for" id="beds" class="formDropdown">
                        <option value="Property for sale">Property for sale</option>
                        <option value="Property for rent">Property for rent</option>
                     </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="formBlock select">
                    <label for="propertyType">Property Type</label><br/>
                    <select name="property_type" id="propertyType" class="formDropdown">
                        <option value="any">Any</option>
                        <option value="Houses">Houses</option>
                        <option value="Apartments">Apartments</option>
                        <option value="Bungalows">Bungalows</option>
                        <option value="Land">Land</option>
                        <option value="Commercial property">Commercial property</option>

                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="formBlock">
                        <label for="price-min">Price Range</label><br/>
                        <div style="float:right; margin-top:-25px;">
                            <div class="priceInput"><input type="text" name="price_min" id="price-min" class="priceInput" /></div>
                            <span style="float:left; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px;">-</span>
                            <div class="priceInput"><input type="text" name="price_max" id="price-max" class="priceInput" /></div>
                        </div><br/>
                        <div class="priceSlider"></div>
                        <div class="priceSliderLabel"><span>0</span><span style="float:right;">800,000</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="formBlock select">
                    <label for="location">Location</label><br/>
                    <input id="tags" type="text" name="location">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="formBlock select">
                    <label for="beds">Beds</label><br/>
                    <select name="beds" id="beds" class="formDropdown">
                        <option value="any">Any</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="formBlock select">
                    <label for="baths">Baths</label><br/>
                    <select name="baths" id="baths" class="formDropdown">
                        <option value="any">Any</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="formBlock select">
                     <label for="area2">Search radius</label><br/>
                    <select name="area" id="area2" class="formDropdown">
                        <option value="any">Any</option>
                        <option value="0.25">within 1/4 mile</option>
                        <option value="0.5">within 1/2 mile</option>
                        <option value="1">within 1 mile</option>
                        <option value="3">within 3 miles</option>
                        <option value="5">within 5 miles</option>
                        <option value="10">within 10 miles</option>
                        <option value="20">within 20 miles</option>
                        <option value="30">within 30 miles</option>
                        <option value="40">within 40 miles</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="formBlock">
                        <label for="price-min">Size Range (Square Feet)</label><br/>
                        <div style="float:right; margin-top:-25px;">
                            <div class="priceInput"><input type="text" name="size_min" id="price-min1" class="priceInput" /></div>
                            <span style="float:left; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px;">-</span>
                            <div class="priceInput"><input type="text" name="size_max" id="price-max1" class="priceInput" /></div>
                        </div><br/>
                        <div class="priceSlider1"></div>
                        <div class="priceSliderLabel"><span>0</span><span style="float:right;">80,000</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="formBlock">
                        <input class="buttonColor" type="submit" name="find_property" value="FIND PROPERTIES" style="margin-top:24px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here when i choose 'any' option, I want to display all the data from my table...

I am using query like below

```
$property_for=$_POST['property_for'];
            $property_type=$_POST['property_type'];
            $price_min=$_POST['price_min'];
            $price_max=$_POST['price_max'];
            $location=$_POST['location'];
            $beds=$_POST['beds'];
            $baths=$_POST['baths'];
            $area=$_POST['area'];
            $size_min=$_POST['size_min'];
            $size_max = $_POST['size_max'];
            $property_listing_for_sale = "";
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE category = '$property_for'  AND bed_rooms = '$beds' AND bath_rooms = '$baths'  ORDER BY date_added DESC") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

I am newbie.. so help me.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Create a Dynamic Drop Down List in PHP populated from MySQL Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691936/how-to-create-a-dynamic-drop-down-list-in-php-populated-from-mysql-database)

Comment: 'I want to display all the data when I choose any option' Is there any Mysql query available...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should work with dynamic query's:

```
$baths = $_POST['baths'];
if ($baths == '*') {
   $query = "select * from properties ";
} else {
   $query = "select * from properties where baths = '$baths'"
}
```

Also you should learn about prepared statements.

A second way is to change your option value to `%`

```
<option value="Any">
```

And then you can use the following query:

```
select * from properties where baths like '$baths'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response But i want to display many thing like that when user choose 'any' option.. That time the script will be large. Is there any other way to reduce script size. Example `SELECT * FROM properties WHERE category = '$property_for' AND location = '$location'   AND bed_rooms = '$beds' AND bath_rooms = '$baths'  ORDER BY date_added DESC` this is my actual query. So how can I use when I am using like above? Thank you so much...

Comment: You can also use `<option value="%">` and sql statement `select * from properties where baths like '$baths' `"

Comment: When i use '%' this sign all values are not fetch out.

Comment: @sivaramkundadam You have changed your query to `like`?

Comment: @Jens you are awesome... Thank you so much.. This is the thing I want.. thank you again...