# how to put a mysql record in a value in dropdown list?

Tags: php

I have a page called update.php, inside my update .php i have a dropdown list of provinces,what i want to happen is that i want to display the value of province in a dropdown list, and also i can select different province if i want it to update..

**here my code for the dropdown list..**

```
<tr>
        <td>Province</td>
        <td>
            <select name="Province" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $province; ?>" id="province" onchange="populate(this.id,'municipality')">
                <option id="">Province</option>
                <option value="Albay">Albay</option>
                <option value="Camarines Norte">Camarines Norte</option>
                <option value="Camarines Sur1">Camarines Sur 1</option>
                <option value="Camarines Sur2">Camarines Sur 2</option>
                <option value="Catanduanes">Catanduanes</option>
                <option value="Masbate">Masbate</option>
                <option value="Sorsogon">Sorsogon</option>
            </select>
        </td>
```

**Code for javacript**

```
function populate(s1,s2){
        var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
        var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
        var optionArray;

        s2.innerHTML = "";
            if(s1.value == "Albay"){
                optionArray = ["|","bacacay|Bacacay","camalig|Camalig","daraga|Daraga","guinobatan|Guinobatan","jovellar|Jovellar","legazpi|Legazpi","libon|Libon","ligao|Ligao","malilipot|Malilipot","malinao|Malinao","manito|Manito","oas|Oas","pioduran|Pioduran","polangui|Polangui","rapu-rapu|Rapu-Rapu","sto. domingo|Sto. Domingo","tabaco|Tabaco","tiwi|Tiwi"];
            }
            else if(s1.value == "Camarines Norte"){
                optionArray = ["|","basud|Basud","capalonga|Capalonga","daet|Daet","imelda|Imelda","jose panganiban|Jose Panganiban","labo mercedes|Labo Mercedes","paracale|Paracale","san vicente|San Vicente","sta. elena|Sta. Elena","talisay|Talisay","vinzons|Vinzons","capalonga|Capalonga"];
            }
            else if(s1.value == "Camarines Sur1"){
                optionArray = ["|","baao|Baao","balatan|Balatan","bato|Bato","buhi|Buhi","bula|Bula","cabusao|Cabusao","del gallego|Del Gallego","gainza|Gainza","iriga city|Iriga City","libmanan|Libmanan","lupi|Lupi","milaor|Milaor","minalabac|Minalabac","nabua|Nabua","pamplona|Pamplona","pasacao|Pasacao","ragay|Ragay","san fernando|San Fernando","sipocot|Sipocot"];
            }
            else if(s1.value == "Camarines Sur2"){
                optionArray = ["|","bombon|Bombon","calabanga|Calabanga","camaligan|Camaligan","canaman|Canaman","caramoan|Caramoan","garchitorena|Garchitorena","goa|Goa","lagonoy|Lagonoy","magarao|Magarao","naga city|Naga City","ocampo|Ocampo","pili|Pili","presentacion|Presentacion","sagnay|Sagnay","san jose|San Jose","siruma|Siruma","tigaon|Tigaon","tinambac|Tinambac"];
            }
            else if(s1.value == "Catanduanes"){
                optionArray = ["|","bagamanoc|Bagamanoc","baras|Baras","bato|Bato","caramoran|Caramoran","gigmoto|Gigmoto","pandan|Pandan","panganiban|Panganiban","san andres|San Andres","san miguel|San Miguel","viga|Viga","virac|Virac"];
            }
            else if(s1.value == "Masbate"){
                optionArray = ["|","aroroy|Aroroy","baleno|Baleno","balud|Balud","batuan|Batuan","cataingan|Cataingan","cawayan|Cawayan","claveria|Claveria","dimasalang|Dimasalang","esperanza|Esperanza","mandaon|Mandaon","masbate|Masbate","milagros east|Milagros East","milagros west|Milagros West","mobo|Mobo","monreal|Monreal","palanas|Palanas","pio v. corpuz|Pio V. Corpuz","placer|Placer","san fernando|San Fernando","san jacinto|San Jacinto","san pascual|San Pascual","sipalay|Sipalay","uson north|Uson North","uson south|Uson South"];
            }
            else if(s1.value == "Sorsogon"){
                optionArray = ["|","bacon|Bacon","barcelona|Barcelona","bulan|Bulan","casiguran|Casiguran","castilla|Castilla","donsol|Donsol","gubat|Gubat","irosin|Irosin","juban|Juban","magallanes|Magallanes","matnog|Matnog","pilar|Pilar","prieto diaz|Prieto Diaz","sorsogon|Sorsogon","sta. magdalena|Sta. Magdalena"];
            }

        for(var option in optionArray){
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = pair[0];
            newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
            s2.options.add(newOption);
          }
        }
```

**here's what i've tried**

```
<tr>
        <td>Land Type</td>
            <?php
                    include_once 'dbconfig.php';

                    $sql = "SELECT Province FROM survey_section";
                    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
                        {
                ?>
            <td><select name="Province" class="form-control">
                <option selected="selected" value="">---</option>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($results as $row)
                        {
                    ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['Province']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Province']; ?></option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: WHere is your code for achieving this?

Comment: You've got an extra double quote (`"`) in your `<select>`

Comment: @MeeneshJain yeah.. i tried the one that i posted..but its not showing..it keeps showing in the dropdownlist the "province"

Comment: @Huey i'm sorry for that..i already updated my question..

Comment: you need to write your option list dynamically with some php codez

Comment: @MattHB but how can do that?can you help me with this?

Comment: a simple search on this site gets you miles.  [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691936/how-to-create-a-dynamic-drop-down-list-in-php-populated-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work

When using html please note correct amount of **"** and **'** starts and ends

```
<select name="Province" class="form-control" 
 value="<?php echo $province; ?>" id="province" onchange="populate(this.id,'municipality')">
    <?php
     // start your php here
     $select_data = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT id_column,name_column from your_table_name LIMIT 10");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_data)){
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row['id_column'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name_column'] ?></option>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
</select>
```

Comment: i forgot to tell you that i'm using PDO and javascript for the dropdown list let me update my code

Comment: only the method name changes in pdo and way of writing thing but the code logic remains the same so use this logic within your code

Comment: @MeeneshKJain i have already tried your code but it still not working

Comment: by the way i only have one dbtable..i use the javascript code above for the select

Comment: what is the  error you get and can you update the question with what you have tried now

Comment: there was no error but the problem now is that all the records in the province field it all show up in the dropdown list

Comment: so you should filter records on the basic of `where` clause and apply a `limit` and also apply `order by`