# MySQL query results is not being Inserted into an option list

Tags: php, html

Following is the code that I am using on my page:

```
<?php

 include ('databaseconnect1.php');

   $sql= "SELECT Categoryid, Categoryname, Categorydescription
          FROM   Categories";

   $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

echo   "<tr>";
echo   '<th>Category </th>';
echo '<td> <select name="Topic_category"> </td>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
echo '<option value="' . $row['Categoryid'] . '">' . $row['Categoryname'] . 
'</option>'; 
       }
echo '</select>';

echo "</tr>"; 

?>
```

The specific problem I am experiencing is that when I launch my page I am getting the following result:

[image]

The result I would like to get is the 'Community Events' and 'Sporting Events' into the Categories drop-down the field. I did prior research to this on this site, but their problems, although similar in nature it was not specific to my problem. I am kind of new to programming so can you assist or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check this answer its, quite similar [how-to-create-a-dynamic-drop-down-list-in-php-populated-from-mysql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691936/how-to-create-a-dynamic-drop-down-list-in-php-populated-from-mysql-database)

Comment: Please make sure that you have pushed data into your MySQL table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `</td>` that it's behind the "Topic_category" to the end of the `select` where the `</select>`

```
echo   "<tr>";

echo   '<th>Category </th>';
echo '<td> <select name="Topic_category"> ';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
echo '<option value="' . $row['Categoryid'] . '">' . $row['Categoryname'] . 
'</option>'; 
       }
echo '</select></td>';

echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your HTML has to stay that way:

```
<th>Category </th>
<td>
  <select>
    <option value="'.$row['Categoryid'].'">$row['Categoryname']</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Remember to put inside the **loop**